# How to dynamically add an image to display in DataGridViewImageColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on WinForms, .NET2 project.

I am using a DataGridView control to display some data.

How can I dynamically add an image to display in a [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.aspx) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically add image.." ?

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.image.aspx) property?

> Gets or sets the image displayed in the cells of this column when the
>   cell's Value property is not set and the cell's ValueIsIcon property
>   is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following...

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Columns.Count; i++) 
{
  TableCell tableCell = gridViewRow.Cells[i];
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img;
  sortDirectionImageControl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
  string imageUrl = "~/Images/Myimage.jpg"; 
  img.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
  img.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "10px");
  tableCell.Wrap = false;
  tableCell.Controls.Add(img);
}
```

Hope I get your question correctly.